# Безопасность в Access 2010

Tags: windows, access

Здравствуйте.

Возникла ситуация: при запуске базы данных, access выдает запрос на блокировку небезопасных выражений. По ошибке была нажата кнопка заблокировать. Теперь ни в одной базе на данном компьютере не работает vba. На компьютере стоит windows xp home edition, doctor web и включен виндовский брандмауэр. В интернете нашел? что нужно добавить расположение базы в надежное и сделать изменение в реестре, но не помогло. Подскажите? что делать.

Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 1):

У меня в надежном расположении только это:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\ACCWIZ\